# Mailcore: Listen for failed request

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, mailcore2

I've integrated with Gmail OAuth and have it working pretty good. The only remaining issue is using the `refreshToken` to retrieve a new `accessToken` when it expires. I persist both of these in CoreData so I have easy access to them anywhere in my app. My problem is that I don't know where to do the refresh. **Does Mailcore provide an NSNotification or similar when a request fails?** This way I know that the token needs refreshed and I can refresh it and retry the request with the new token.

Update:

My current solution is simply to refresh the token every time the app becomes active. I would prefer to only refresh the token when it expires (i.e. when a request fails).

Comment: With OAuth2, check the error of the operations. When there's an authentication error, it probably means that the token is expired.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on a quite a large project so I was hoping for something more global (e.g. an NSNotification posted when there is an operation error) but I can work something similar out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomly guessing when a good time to update the token would be, use the 'expires_in' value to run some kind of logic about whether or not enough time has passed to warrant a refresh of the token.Or What I do is grab the token the first time and set a timestamp. Then, on the next call to do anything IMAP/SMTP related I check if the current timestamp is >= 50 minutes since the last update (tokens are only good for an hour so this seems to work well).

Hope this helps! :)